# Change UserCreationForm description in django

Tags: django

I created my own user class according to:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/

Having this user created I would like to change description of the creation form. For now it's "First, enter a username and password. Then, you'll be able to edit more user options.".

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I checked all meta fields and found how to change label of field but still can't figure out how to accomplish change of form description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not in the form at all, it's just in a template:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/auth/user/add_form.html

Comment: Thank you, I hoped that there is some meta field called description or sth.

Answer (score 2):

Extension of Daniel answer:

The Django template engine has a defined order for loading templates. When it loads a template, it uses the first template that matches the name. You can override admin templates by using the same directory structure and file names.

You can add a custom admin template in the next steps:

- Add template in the root of your project [image]
- Include the templates (settings.py) [image]

Enjoy :)